Unable to load dynamic library 'ddtrace' (tried: C:\PHP7\ext\ddtrace (The specified module could not be found.), when adding Datadog APM with php
I am trying to add datadog APM to my php app which is running on IIS, but while testing the added executables and running php -m I am getting the error PHP Startup: **Unable to load dynamic library 'ddtrace' (tried: C:\PHP7\ext\ddtrace (The specified module could not be found.), **C:\PHP7\ext\php_ddtrac
I have tried upgrading the php version to 8.
I checked the ddtrace file permission and it is having all rights.
I tried adding the path to this dll file in the environment variable.
My expectation is that php should load dynamic library 'ddtrace'


Screenshot of the Ext folder having the ddtrace.dll


Did you check your phpinfo() to confirm that the extension_dir is correct? did you install the modules in that directory?

No it does not exist as per the output of the phpinfo(), I am adding the screenshot of the output. The dll files exists in the ext folder as well as in the php.ini

You probably know that PHP 7 reached end of life a few years ago.

There was issue with the file download, earlier I was downloading php_ddtrac directly using browser, later I tried downloading using curl on git bash and it started working. Thanks for your responses.

Each PHP installation requires its own specific extensions. A DLL extension designed for PHP8 will very often not work under PHP7.
You therefore need to download the official datadog trace DLL designed for your specific version of PHP. From what I can see from your phpinfo(), you need a 64-bits NON threadsafe version.
